# Компиляция в Си и работами со строками

Tags: c++, c

Суть ошибки вот в чём, надо составить программу, которая на входе получает "базис счисления" и "последовательность цифр" Базис может принимать значение 2, 8, 16. В итоге с 8-кой не получается, что бы ни ввёл, он выводим number is wrong. Не могу понять в чём ошибка, из - за этого уже не уверен верно ли работает с двойкой.

**Вот сам код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int bazis;
    char str[10] = {0};
    int length;
    printf("┬тхфшЄх срчшё ш яюёыхфютрЄхы№эюёЄ№: ");
    scanf("%d %6s", &bazis, str);
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0' && i < 6; i++) {
        length++;
    }
if(bazis != 2 && bazis != 8 && bazis != 16) {
        printf("Base is wrong.\n");
    }
else {

    if(bazis = 2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] != '0' && str[i] != '1') {
                printf("Number is wrong.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(bazis = 8) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(str[i] >= '8') {
                printf("Number is wrong.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: _if(bazis = 2)_ - Должно быть два знака =. Два! if(bazis == 2)

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: Есть хитрый трюк чтобы избежать таких проблем - писать константу слева: `2 = bazis`, тогда компилятор вам сразу укажет на ошибку

Comment: Или, вместо того, чтобы ломать себе глаза об `2 == bazis`, можно просто включить предупреждения в настройках компилятора.